# -bash: pylint: command not found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, terminal, pip, pylint

I have been trying to install pylint to be used on terminal, but have been unsuccessful in using it. The installation gets successful, but whenever I try to run pylint command, it returns the following error -

```
-bash: pylint: command not found
```

I have tried using following commands -

```
pip install pylint
python -m pip install pylint
sudo pip install pylint
sudo -H pip install pylint
```

I have uninstalled it, before trying each of the above command, but everytime I install it, the installation gets successful, but I am unable to use it on command line. I know it's something silly I am missing.

Here's the output I get on installation -

```
My-Mac:Dev noob$ sudo -H pip install pylint
Collecting pylint
  Using cached pylint-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: isort>=4.2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools-lru-cache; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid<1.5.0,>=1.4.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from astroid<1.5.0,>=1.4.5->pylint)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from astroid<1.5.0,>=1.4.5->pylint)
Installing collected packages: pylint
Successfully installed pylint-1.6.5
```

PS: I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3 on a Macbook pro Late 2011, in case this is relevant.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358987/which-files-get-installed-when-pip-installing-pylint/59064477#59064477

Answer (score 13):

The issue is installed python executables aren't being added to your path. Our paths don't look exactly the same (probably because different python versions, I'm not sure) but mine is

```
host:~ williamhammond$ pip install pylint
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid<3,>=2.2.0 in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pylint) (2.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: isort<5,>=4.2.5 in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pylint) (4.3.21)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pylint) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typed-ast>=1.3.0; implementation_name == "cpython" in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint) (1.4.1)
```

I was seeing the same issues as you until I looked here

```
host:~ williamhammond$ ls /Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/bin/
dmypy           epylint         isort           mypy            pep8            pylint          pyreverse       stubgen         symilar
```

Once you add this to your path like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/williamhammond/Library/Python/3.7/bin/
```

you should be able to use pylint. To make this change permanent make sure to add the command to your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

For the very last comment in the response given by William Hammond on [making this change permanent](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/) make sure to add the command to your `~/.bashrc`, you'd find the hyperlink above a useful guide to get this done:

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the file path, then input that into the files to take me directly to where the scripts are stored then I copied all the scripts there and added them to the same folder where I have the code that I would like it to work on..

Summary: I moved the files downloaded on path.