# which files get installed when `pip` installing `pylint`?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pylint

I ran `pip install --user pylint` and did not notice any error.  However, `pylint foo.py` throws the error `pylint: command not found`.

Comparing with [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) it looks like I only have a subset on my computer (see below).  At any rate, I don't have any *file* named `pylint`.

**Is there anything I can install by hand if it didn't work straight out-of-the-box?**

Here are the files that I have:

under `/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint`:
`__init__.py`
`__init__.pyc`
`__main__.py`
`__main__.pyc`
`__pkginfo__.py`
`__pkginfo__.pyc`
`checkers`
`config.py`
`config.pyc`
`epylint.py`
`epylint.pyc`
`exceptions.py`
`exceptions.pyc`
`extensions`
`graph.py`
`graph.pyc`
`interfaces.py`
`interfaces.pyc`
`lint.py`
`lint.pyc`
`pyreverse`
`reporters`
`test`
`testutils.py`
`testutils.pyc`
`utils.py`
`utils.pyc`

(I am not listing the files within the subdirectories `checkers`, etc.)

and there is also another folder, 
`/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint-1.9.2.dist-info` with
`DESCRIPTION.rst`
`INSTALLER`
`METADATA`
`RECORD`
`WHEEL`
`entry_points.txt`
`metadata.json`
`top_level.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be more helpful if errors/output from your `pip` run was shared, I guess there are more details in pip logs. Usually something like this is a good hint where you can find the errors:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /some/path
```

I'd first check if `pylint` is actually installed

```
pip list | grep pylint
```

If not, then follow the errors from `pip install`. But if `pylint` is available yet  running `pylint` is the problem (command not found), it's because the command line entry point is not installed properly. Then it may be run like this:

```
python -m pylint --help
```

On a side note,  generally using [virtual environments](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) are a nice way to install packages/software on user accessible paths, and to install executable programs (as opposed to library packages) to local user accessible paths, I suggest using something like [pipsi](https://pypi.org/project/pipsi/) instead of `pip`, which handles creating/activating the `virtualenv` automatically.

**Update**

As discussed on the comments, since your current installation is OK and it's just the command line entry point missing, you could add a Python file (with exec permissions) somewhere in your path for each of the [entry points](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/e17b37c5cddb620b009e91a9bc37aa333502ad74/setup.py#L145), like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylint import run_pylint
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_pylint()
```

Comment: The reason I didn't share the output after running `pip` is that I wasn't sure what it does to my system if I un-install and re-install things multiple times.  As I wrote in my question, there weren't any errors reported (as far as I had noticed).

Comment: I should have clarified: `python -m pylint foo.py` was already working, but not `pylint foo.py`.  Thanks for formulating the problem for me: "The command line entry point is not installed"!  Anything I can do now that `pylint` is installed?  I have tried reinstalling it, but the problem seems to persist.  I guess now is the time for to actually start using virtual environments...

Comment: If you see `pylint` in your `pip list`, then you can `pip uninstall pylint` to clear things out. `virtualenvs` are quite helpful, and `pipsi` makes it easier to use them. In this case, I suggest `pipsi`. Once pipsi is installed, it'll handle the rest using `virtualenvs` on user accessible paths. the whole thing goes like: `sudo pip install pipsi; pipsi install pylint; pylint --help`

Comment: I updated the answer in case you preferred to keep using existing installation.

Comment: Thank you! ```pip uninstall pylint``` and re-install pylint works!

Answer (score 1):

Look if you have `pylint` in `/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7/bin/`. If yes — add the directory to your `$PATH`. If no — list files using `pip show --files pylint`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer about this point: I have a *folder* named `pylint`, but no *file* with that name.  Also, there is no issue with my $PATH.